# Write a function that checks if a given binary search tree contains a given value using python

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have tried almost everthing i pass the first test case but not the last two 
which are correctness and performance on large trees wrong and it has to return True or False.

```
import collections


class BinarySearchTree:
      Node = collections.namedtuple('Node', ['left', 'right', 'value'])

      @staticmethod
      def contains(root, value):
          if root.value == value:
              return True
          elif root.value < value:
               return root.right.value == value #I am using == to return True or  
                                         #False
          else:
              return root.right.value == value


n1 = BinarySearchTree.Node(value=1, left=None, right=None)
n3 = BinarySearchTree.Node(value=3, left=None, right=None)
n2 = BinarySearchTree.Node(value=2, left=n1, right=n3)


print(BinarySearchTree.contains(n2, 3))
```

how can i traverse a tuple within a tuple within a tuple?

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code.

> 1. Previous code was for one node not the whole tree.
> 2. else was also checking the right node and not the left node.

```
import collections


class BinarySearchTree:
      Node = collections.namedtuple('Node', ['left', 'right', 'value'])


  @staticmethod
  def contains(root, value):
      if root.value == value:
          return True
      elif root.value < value:
          if root.right == None:
               return False
          else:
               return BinarySearchTree.contains(root.right,value)
        #root.right.value == value #I am using == to return True or  
                                     #False
      else:
          if root.left == None:
              return False
          else:
              return BinarySearchTree.contains(root.left,value)
          #root.right.value == value


n4 = BinarySearchTree.Node(value=4, left=None, right=None)
n0 = BinarySearchTree.Node(value=0, left=None, right=None)
n1 = BinarySearchTree.Node(value=1, left=n0, right=None)
n3 = BinarySearchTree.Node(value=3, left=None, right=n4)
n2 = BinarySearchTree.Node(value=2, left=n1, right=n3)


print(BinarySearchTree.contains(n2, 14))
```